# snapshot error: Database version comes from future version of the client: 4

Tags: snapshot

When I go to add a validator to a parachain, using the snapshot(https://ksm-rocksdb.polkashots.io/) does tell me that the db version is wrong:

```
Error: Service(Client(Backend("Database version comes from future version of the client: 4"))
```

Comment: Have you considered updating you Polkadot client?